# Dice probabilities, $2$ of $3$

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least two of three dice will roll a three or higher?  There must be an equation that would allow one to expand this to any number of dice.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you want at least $m$ successes out of $n$ experiments, with a chance for success of $p$. Then if $q = 1-p$, the chance is:

$$\sum_{k=m}^n \binom{n}{k} p^kq^{n-k}$$

In your case, $n = 3$, $m = 2$ and $p = \frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

**If dices are non-identical:** $$\frac{6\times4\times4}{6\times6\times6}=\frac49\approx44.4\%$$

Comment: it should be 44.444...%.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of rolling at least $i$ is $1-\frac {i-1}6=\frac {7-i}{6}$. Now, using the binomium of Newton, we get that there are $\binom nk$ possibilities for rolling exactly $k$ times larger than $i$ in $n$ rolls. Thus, the probability of rolling $k$ times at least $i$ is $$\binom nk \left(\frac {7-i}6\right)^k\left(\frac{i-1}6\right)^{n-k}$$
Summing this from $k=t$ to $n$ gives the probability of rolling at least $t$ times $i$ or higher:
$$\sum_{k=t}^n\binom nk \left(\frac {7-i}6\right)^k\left(\frac{i-1}6\right)^{n-k}$$

Setting $i=3$, $n=3$ and $t=2$ gives
$$
3\cdot \left(\frac 23\right)^2\frac13+\frac 23\left(\frac 13\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to know the probability of event $Y$: event $X$ to be successful (roll a number $x_0=3$ or higher) **at least** $m=2$ of $n=3$ times. That's the same as a Binomial Distribution:
$$P(Y|x_0,m,n)=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Where $p$ is the probability of event $X$ ocurring (roll $x_0$ or higher in a dice), that is
$$p=P(X\geq x_0)=1-\frac{x_0-1}{6}=\frac{7-x_0}{6}$$

Then
$$P(Y|x_0,m,n)=\frac{1}{6^n}\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{n}{k}({7-x_0})^k(x_0-1)^{n-k}$$